# Comprobar que la variable sea un número en Bash

Tags: bash

Quisiera comprobar en un bucle while que el valor introducido en una variable sea un número y que dicho número esté entre 1 y 5.

Estoy probando esto, pero no funciona:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ejercicio 7

while [[ $( grep -vE "[1-5]" $OPTION ) || $OPTION -lt 1 || $OPTION -gt 5 ]]
do
    echo "Escoche la operación:"
    echo "1. Sumar"
    echo "2. Restar"
    echo "3. Multiplicar"
    echo "4. Dividir"
    echo "5. salir" 

    read OPTION
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada, hasta donde comprendo, `bash` no tiene algo como "variables por tipo": todo es una cadena. No tengo forma de demostrarlo pero es hasta donde comprendo. Esto lo digo porque comprobar si una variable es un número o no, dependería de una estrategia sobre ciertos caracteres, en lugar de pedir algo como "un tipo (int, str, varchar, class, etc)".

Ahora, una opción que te doy es utilizar una especie de `while-do` (no existe por default en `bash`, pero se puede implementar) y una sencilla expresión regular para hacer todo al mismo tiempo (tanto verificar si es un número como saber si está entre 1 y 5) y salir si es 5.

```
#!/bin/bash
lectura() {
    echo "Escoche la operación:"
    echo "1. Sumar"
    echo "2. Restar"
    echo "3. Multiplicar"
    echo "4. Dividir"
    echo "5. salir"

    read -p "Opción: " opcion #  read —con el parámetro "-p"—,
                              #+ muestra como prompt la cadena "Opción: "
}


# Aquí emulamos el while-do
while #  Como while es de la forma: while lista_de_comandos; do otra_lista_de_comandos; done
      #+ aquí la lista de comandos será la función "lectura" y después el evaluador integrado
      #+ (built-in) "[[" de la forma: [[ <expresiones compuestas> ]]
    lectura # Se ejecuta la función lectura
    [[ "$opcion" -ne 5 ]]  # Se evalua la variable "opcion"; si no es 5, entonces continua.
do
    [[ ! "$opcion" =~ ^[1-5]$ ]] && echo "El valor tiene que ser entre 1 y 5"
    #|_________________________|  |__ Este operador indica que se va a ejecutar lo que
    #             |                   esté a la derecha siempre y cuando el estado salida
    #             |                   del comando de la izquierda sea 0. Puedes usarlo
    #             |                   como una clase de short-if.
    #             |
    #             |__ Aquí se evalua si la variable "opcion" no (con "!") es emparejada
    #                 (con el operador "<valor> =~ <expresión regular>") con un
    #                 sólo caracter entre 1 y 5.
    #                 En caso de que se cumpla la condición (que no sea un caracter
    #                 que esté en la lista [12345]) entonces se evalua como verdadero, es
    #                 decir, regresa 0.
done
```

#### Aclaración sobre la expresión regular.

La expresión regular `^[1-5]$` es una sencilla forma de saber si una cadena cumple con el patrón: inicia con (esto indica que inicia al principio de linea: `^`) un sólo elemento de la lista [12345] (con [1-5] que es un rango inclusivo), y luego termina (esto indica que finaliza al final de línea: `$`). Es decir: un sólo número entre 1 y 5.

Hasta aquí puedes copiar y pegar lo anterior.

### Versión un poquito sofisticada e innecesaria, pero muy ilustrativa.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A operaciones #  Declaramos un array asociativo con las operaciones
                       #+ y los numeramos como querramos.
operaciones=(
    [1]=Sumar
    [2]=Restar
    [3]=Multiplicar
    [4]=Dividir
    [5]=salir
)

lectura() {

: << _doc_

    En lugar de usar muchos "echo", podemos hacer uso de un "here-document"
    sobre cat. El here-document se indica con "<<" en un: 
expresión << delimitador
    here-document
delimitador

    Un here-document es un tipo de redireccionamiento que le indica a
    la shell que lea todo hasta que llegue a un delimitador. En este caso
    particular le voy a llamar "EOF".

    cat va a leer del stdin porque se lo indicamos con "-".

_doc_

    cat - << EOF
Escoche la operación:
$( : << _eof 

    Estamos dentro de un command substitution, el cual sustituye lo que
    se ejecute dentro de la subshell 
    (delimitada con los paréntesis "(<una infinidad de comandos>)"). 
    Y lo que sustituiremos será por un menú construido a través de una iteración sobre
    los elementos del array asociativo "operaciones".

_eof

  for key in ${!operaciones[@]}; do #  Aquí iteramos sobre las claves del
                                    #+ array asociativo.
      printf "%s. %s\n" \
          $key \
          ${operaciones[$key]}      #  Usamos printf para formatear la salida
                                    #+ de la forma "<numero>. <operacon>, como "1. Sumar"
  done
)
EOF
#|_______ Aquí termina el menú dinámico.

    read -p "Operación: " opcion
}


while  
    lectura 
    [[ "$opcion" -ne 5 ]]  
do
    [[ ! "$opcion" =~ ^[1-5]$ ]] && echo "El valor tiene que ser entre 1 y 5"
done
```

### Con el uso de un `select`.

En este caso, en lugar de usar un `while`, propongo el uso del `select` de `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare opciones=( 
    Sumar 
    Restar 
    Multiplicar 
    Dividir 
    Salir 
)

PS3="Prompt personalizado. Elige una opcion: " #  Esto se mostrará en el select
                                               #+ como prompt.

#[START] Ejemplos de funciones
sumar() {
    echo "aqui se suma"
}

restar() {
    echo "aqui se resta"
}
#[END] Ejemplos de funciones

select opcion in ${opciones[@]}; do
    case "$REPLY" in  # $REPLY tiene la respuesta que se ingresa.
        1 )
            sumar
            ;;
        2 )
            restar
            ;;
        3 )
            echo Elegiste Multiplicar.
            # Se hace multiplicación.
            ;;
        4 )
            echo Elegiste Dividir.
            # Se hace división.
            ;;
        5 )
            echo Elegiste Salir.
            exit
            ;;
        * )
            echo Debe ser un número entre 1 y 5
            continue # Resume la iteración.
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Para validar si la variable es un número puedes decir:

```
[[ "$valor" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

---

Para validar que el número está entre 1 y 5 dirías:

```
[[ "$valor" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$valor" -ge 1 ] && [ "$valor" -le 5 ]
```

---

La primera vez estás validando el valor de "$OPTION" antes de darle ningún dato. Lo que iría bien es algo así como un do_while, que puedes expresar así, negando la expresión indicada arriba para que siga leyendo mientras el valor no sea válido:

```
#!/bin/bash

lectura() {
    echo "Escoche la operación:"
    echo "1. Sumar"
    echo "2. Restar"
    echo "3. Multiplicar"
    echo "4. Dividir"
    echo "5. salir"

    read valor
}

lectura
while ! [[ "$valor" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || ! [ "$valor" -ge 1 ] || ! [ "$valor" -le 5 ]
do
    echo "$valor"
    lectura
done
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Soy nuevo en el mundo del scripting en ubuntu y tengo muchas dudas, ¿Podrías decirme por qué añades [] en cada condición?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Porque son condiciones diferentes, cada una necesaria